# How do I get monitor to display true black?

Tags: hdmi, display, screen, chromium

When I change the brightness setting to 0 black #000000 displays as true black with no light coming from the screen. Unfortunately white also dims quite a bit. When I set brightness to 100, black becomes dark grey and light comes from those pixels. I would like to set black to true black while displaying white without dimming.

My contrast is currently set to 100 I currently own a ACER X223w monitor. I am only displaying black and white. I am displaying a website in chromium in kiosk mode Raspberry Pi connected through HDMI

Is there any way to this?

Comment: Hi! Do you really think this is related to the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes I'm running all the displays from the rapsberry pi, i was hoping there were configuration files I could edit or something like that to help my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is likely just the limitations of your monitor.

Unless you are using an OLED display; in which each pixel is its own light source you will never be able to get true black. By increasing the brightness you are increasing the level of back-lighting your monitor is doing. As a result of this the entire screen is showing the back-lighting more, and therefore causing a grey hue .